# Math.abs(Integer) not working, can't convert Integer to int

Tags: java, comparator

I'm implementing a Comparator that sorts based on absolute value. All I (think) I need is this single line of code:

```
public int compare(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
    return Math.abs(int1).compareTo(Math.abs(int2));
}
```

The error: `'no suitable method found for abs(Integer)`'

I thought that Java unboxes the Integer object to int?

I tried pulling the int value from the two Integer objects using .intValue(), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you want `return Integer.compare(Math.abs(int1), Math.abs(int2));`

Comment: What is the return type of `Math#abs`?

Comment: Decompose your code a bit and the problem will become apparent.  Hint: `Math.abs(anIntegerObject)` works fine and isn't your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , I don't think so. I want my comparator to just use the natural ordering of integers, which is why I called compareTo()

Comment: @user8:  It will unbox to `int` if the return type is actually an `Integer`.

Comment: as has been asked by @SotiriosDelimanolis, what does `Math.abs(...)` return? So yes, you DO want to use it and in fact must use it. And this *does* give you the "natural ordering of ints".

Comment: .... unless you prefer receiving the error message.

Comment: BTW a quirk of Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE. You can cast it to a long to ensure this isn't a problem.

Comment: You are saying -1 == 1 so if you use this on a Set or Map one will replace the other.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yup! I'm implementing this to see firsthand how it breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Math#abs(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) will indeed unbox `Integer` to `int` if you pass it as argument, but then it will return result as `int` which is primitive type, so it doesn't have *any* methods, so you can't chain `.compareTo` to it.

You are probably looking for something like

```
Integer.compare(Math.abs(int1), int2);
```

or (depending on version of your question)

```
Integer.compare(Math.abs(int1), Math.abs(int2));
```